# Hover effect on button

Tags: css, button

I have the following code for my "Add to cart" button

```
#addToCart {
  background-color: #00AFEF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;

}
```

I would like to add a hover effect on the button to make the color 10% darker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `SASS`, you can add a variable and use `darken` and `:hover` in your `CSS`, like so:

```
$colour: #00AFEF;

#addToCart {
  background-color: $colour;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;

}
#addToCart:hover {
  darken($colour, 10%);
}
```

Otherwise, another trick is to change the `opacity` with `:hover`:

```
#addToCart:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this code must have conflicted with some other css variables as the site appears as text only now. Please advise

Comment: It happens when I add the #addToCart:hover element

Comment: Remove the $colour

Comment: Perfect, the opacity did the trick :) Thank you so much. Could you also advise how I can add a gradient to the color of the button?

Answer (score 3):

This may help you!

```css
#addToCart {
  background-color: #00AFEF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;

}
#addToCart:hover{background-color:#209bc7}
```

```html
<button id="addToCart">Button</button>
```